# Select statement involving manipulation of dates(oldest-inbetween-latest)

Tags: sql-server, select

[image]

I have this table and the user at the home page will pick an fa id which will be able to print the data for that specific data. now what i want to achieve is to be able to print the data using the same FAID which is for example is one and ill be able to get the userID of 6(Eff_from = 2/3/2012) which is the next date of FAID = 1 (Eff_to(2/2/2012).

```
 $sql_exp = "SELECT top 1 b.LaptopID, b.Eff_to
FROM    dbo.users a
        INNER JOIN dbo.FA_Laptop b
            ON a.userID = b.UserID
WHERE b.LaptopID=
    (SELECT x.LaptopID 
    FROM FA_Laptop x
     WHERE x.FAID = $faidf) order by b.Eff_to desc, b.FAID"
```

with this code i could only print the latest date with latter FAID

Comment: Can you make the example and the question a bit more clear? I did not understand well. Do you need a kind of chain of dates? Which version of Sql Server do you have?

Comment: updated the questo good sir. what im trying to do is when a user selects FAID = 1 which has the Eff_to(2/2/2012) it will display the one with date which is next 2/2/2012 which is FAID = 3. those dates are just random sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
Declare @FA_Laptop table 
(FAID int,LaptopID int,userId int,Eff_from date,Eff_to date)

Insert into @FA_Laptop
values
(1,39,1,'1/1/2012','2/2/2012'),
(2,39,4,'5/5/2012','7/7/2012'),
(3,39,6,'2/3/2012','5/4/2012'),
(4,39,8,'7/8/2012','12/24/2012')

;with cte as
(
 Select FAID,LaptopID,userID,Eff_to
 from @FA_Laptop where FAID=1 //Get the value from your PHP page
)
Select c.faid,f.faid as nextFAID,c.userID,f.userId as nextUserID,c.laptopId,
f.laptopId as nextLaptopID from cte c  left join   @FA_Laptop f 
on f.Eff_from=dateadd(day,1,c.eff_to)

Result :

faid  nextFAID  userID    nextUserID    laptopId    nextLaptopID
 1      3             1      6            39               39
```

Using Subquery

```
Select temp.faid,temp.userID,f.userId as nextUserID,temp.laptopId,
f.laptopId as nextLaptopID
from 
(
Select FAID,LaptopID,userID,Eff_to
from @FA_Laptop where FAID=1
) temp  
left join   @FA_Laptop f 
on f.Eff_from=dateadd(day,1,temp.eff_to)
```

Updated :

```
SELECT  temp.LaptopID, temp.Eff_to,f.userId as nextUserID,
        f.laptopId as nextLaptopID
FROM    dbo.users a
inner join 
(
  Select FAID,LaptopID,userID,Eff_to
  from FA_Laptop where FAID=$faidf
) temp
on a.userID = temp.UserID
left join   FA_Laptop f 
on f.Eff_from=dateadd(day,1,temp.eff_to)
```

Update 2:

Check [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e83e/2) for the result

the query is

```
SELECT  fl.userId as nextUserID,fl.eff_from,
        fl.laptopId as nextLaptopID
FROM  FA_Laptop f
inner join   FA_Laptop fl 
on fl.Eff_from=dateadd(day,1,f.eff_to) and f.faid=$faidf
inner join users a
on a.userID=fl.userID
```

Comment: sorry my good sir but im confused to wha is this and bould barely analyze it. could you somehow simplify it or connect it to my "attempt" codes above? sorry i think this sounds rude but im very thankful of this though i guess i know what is too much for my brain as of the moment hehe

Comment: Kindly tell me what  data is present in user table and it would better if you can post the result which you want

Comment: user table has userID(PK), EmployeeName, EmployeeID.  the result i want is when the user picks FAID 1 it will display the employee with the "next" Eff_from(2/2/2012) of FAID 1 which is FAID 3 which has Eff_from of 2/3/2012. i want to display the user of FAID 3 which has the "next" date

Comment: Check Update2 . I have created the query in sql fiddle .Let me know if the result is correct